# Visual Studio 2017 - C# - Code Generation - GetHashCode() - Initial Value - Explanation needed

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, code-generation, gethashcode

I've used the code generation feature for `GetHashCode` the first time. I think it is a great thing. But I don't understand the first line of code. How is the number calculated?
If I add more fields to the `GetHashCode` algorithm (e.g. a field from a parent class) do I need to change this number in the first line of code?

```
public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        var hashCode = 589741190;
        hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + EqualityComparer<string>.Default.GetHashCode(SyncKey);
        hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + EqualityComparer<string>.Default.GetHashCode(Name);
        hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + EqualityComparer<string>.Default.GetHashCode(Firstname);
        hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + EqualityComparer<string>.Default.GetHashCode(Lastname);
        hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + EqualityComparer<string>.Default.GetHashCode(Notes);
        hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + EqualityComparer<DateTime?>.Default.GetHashCode(Birthdate);
        return hashCode;
    }
```

Comment: The numbers involved are (usually) just relatively prime and (often) somewhat large-ish. There's no more magic than that. And no, you don't need to change these numbers, though you *will* find examples of different numbers from different implementations. It doesn't mean anything though, they're just chosen and used.

Answer (score 2):

Mostly prime numbers are used for hashing functions. However `589741190` is not a prime number. I don't know where you got the code from, but I think this number is just randomly chosen. (This does not mean that this number is bad for hashing).

There is lots of info to read here regarding this function from the official .NET repo:

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/14354

Comment: Neither is 1521134295 a prime number: it can be divided by 3 and by 5 (and perhaps many more numbers).